# How to write on terminal after login with telnet to remote machine using python

Tags: python-2.7, telnetlib

I am trying to connect a remote machine in python. I used telnetlib module and could connect to machine after entering login id and password as

tn = Telnet("HOST IP")

tn.write("UID")

tn.write("PWD")

After entering password, the terminal connects to the remote machine which is a linux based software [having its own IP address(HOST IP).]

Then after If I try to give a command e.g. tn.write("cd //tmp/media/..) to go to its various folders then it does not work and when checked to see what the screen is showing with

tn.read_very_eager()

error comes up as :

""\r\n\r\n\r\nBusyBox v1.19.4 (2012-07-19 22:27:43 CEST) built-in shell (ash)\r\n
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.\r\n\r\n~ # ""

I wanted to know if there is any method in Python as we have in PERL as **$telnet->cmd ("cd //tmp/media/..)**

Any suggestions are welcomed if you can give an example!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should try to login to the machine using `telnet`, then you will notice you will login into BusyBox. That string you print not an error it is hte normal BusyBox prompt.

It might not be what you expected, I only know BusyBox from Linux boxes that were unable to properly boot.